# Unexpected Keyword argument using formset_factory

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on a project in which a teacher can add marks to his students, I want to use formset_factory so the teacher can add many marks at the same time, but I want a teacher to see only his students, and not the students who are not in his class.

I got it when using a single form, but when I try to use the formset_factory, I get this error:

**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

This is my working code
in views:

```
  class AddNotaBlock(FormView):

template_name='notas/insertar_nota.html'
   
form_class= NotaCreateFormTeacher
success_url= reverse_lazy('home')

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """ Passes the request object to the form class.
     This is necessary to only display members that belong to a given user"""

    kwargs = super(AddNotaBlock, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs
```

in forms:

```
  class NotaCreateFormTeacher(ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    

    self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super(NotaCreateFormTeacher, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    usuario=self.request.user
    profe=Teacher_profile.objects.get(profesor=usuario)
    colegio=profe.colegio
    self.fields['Username'].queryset = Student_profile.objects.filter(
        colegio=colegio)
    



class Meta:
    model = Nota
    fields = ('Username', 'nota', 'colegio')
    widgets= {'colegio':HiddenInput()}



  formset=formset_factory(NotaCreateFormTeacher, extra=2)
```

when I use:

```
  form_class= NotaCreateFormTeacher
```

Everything works (but only a form is displayed)
If I use:

```
  form_class=formset
```

I get the unexpected keyword argument error:

**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass this as [**`form_kwargs=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms), so:

```
class AddNotaBlock(FormView):
    template_name = 'notas/insertar_nota.html'
    form_class = formset
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.setdefault('form_kwargs', {})['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```